# Any working example recording a (e.g. rtsp) stream to a local MP4 file with ffmpeg/libav?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, record, rtsp, libav

I'm looking for a working and not-out-dated script how to record an e.g. rtsp input stream to a local file (mp4) with ffmpeg/libav. If you could point me to one or post one, many thanks in advance. I'm searching for many hours and I haven't got any experience with this topic.

A lot of examples, libs, etc. are outdated, but I want to use ffmpeg >= v3.3.

Any special things I have to consider (when compiling ffmpeg, or when saving local file to iOS device)?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Yes, you're right, I want to use libav libs and I'm not working with the cli tool.

Answer (score -1):

Ffmpeg syntax is very straight forward.

```
ffmpeg [global_options] {[input_file_options] -i input_url} ... {[output_file_options] output_url} ...
```

So, if you don´t need to reencode or decode your RTPS video stream, you can simply  run:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://your_stream_url your_file_name.format
```

Where format could be avi, mp4, flv or others, ffmpeg you automatic package your stream to the output file.

More information here.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

> Any special things I have to consider (when compiling ffmpeg, or when
>   saving local file to iOS device)?

Do you need to compile ffmpeg for an specific reason? I belive libav is enable on the executable you could download from the site.

Comment: Thx for your reply Tadeu, but I'm looking for an programmatical example with C, C++ or ObjC with the libav libs. To be more specific, I want to record a rtsp or rtp stream within an iOS app and save it to a local .mp4.

Comment: You could try gstreamer and gst-rtsp-server. Both até very low level C but they have iOS interfaces.